# Check if RS232 response contains malformed chars

Tags: android, arduino, serial-port

I have **android** platform on one end and **arduino** on the other, connected via **serial**. Everything works fine, however in some cases arduino restarts itself and causes a flow of unknown characters while its restarting to the serial.

Here is a serial log while **arduino** is rebooting:

> �z������"&O�Z&���B
>   ���F  �*��cd*�:{����t�>��+������2�~����.  ���r���DD���^��*.�.B�.��ڮ2t��Z:��,R��A�ڢr��Ck*ˡ���.-���N^���b�����^���

Question is, how can I check on **android** end if the response was malformed?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add some kind of "framing" to your messages. CR/LF isn't enough.

For example, put a special "preamble" at the front, and watch for it on the Android side. Choose something that will not occur in the body ("payload") of the message.  And choose something that is very unlikely to occur in the random chars that show up on a reboot, a couple of chars long.

You could also put a CRC at the end.  "Fletcher" is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using simple solution like this:

```
private String filterData(String receivedStr) {
    if (receivedStr.contains(RECV_HEADER) && receivedStr.contains(mReadRules.RECV_END)) {
        int header_pos = receivedStr.indexOf(RECV_HEADER);
        int crc_pos = receivedStr.indexOf(RECV_END);

        return receivedStr.substring(header_pos, crc_pos);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It also extracts message if its wrapped around with malformed data.